# Create a branch with specific PRs included from master

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I have a `master` branch and a `release` branch. I want to create another branch that includes the changes from the `release` branch but at the same time include specific changes from `master`. How do I do that?
The changes from `release` branch are already in the `master`. So do I create a branch off of master or release branch?
The changes from release branch are already in production and its closed.

Comment: Git does not "include changes". It knows nothing of "changes". It does not "include PRs" either. Your _entire project_ in some state or other is in the commit at the tip of the branch. What you branch off of is mostly a matter of what state of your project you want to start with on your branch and what branch you intend to merge to later.

Answer (score 0):

if changes are already there in the master branch so then create a branch from the master so all those changes will be there in new branch

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposed solution:

1. Create a branch from **release** by `git chechout release-branch -B new-branch`.
2. Get log of master branch too and **write down the commit hash** you are interested in by `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`.
3. Merge the single master commit into the new branch by `git cherry-pick {{COMMIT_HASH}}`.

Tell me if I understood what you are asking.